Google assistant
Is this possible in android app

User will say hey google start an alert

Assistant diaog will list the list of schools and show and will ask to select the school(which will be fetched from my app)

User will select school

Assistant will fetch the type with respect to school name and list the types in assistant dialog

Then user will select an alert

Assistant will trigger the new api with type and school.


Conversational action is deprecated now so could not find any other solution.
Also Google assistant plugin in android studio deprecated.

On Android device, Google Assistant invocation of App Actions and Built-In Intents (BII) is one-way. Once your Android app takes over, the Google Assistant part is done. You can build your own voice interaction within your own app but not with Google Assistant.
